# Redirection to a .jsp from a servlet

Tags: jsp, servlets

i have a problem in my java EE code. I want to be redirected to a .jsp from my servlet's doPost() method. But nothing happens at the end of the doPost() execution. I'm on the same page before the execution of the doPost method.Can somebody helps me please?

doPost() method :

```
  public static final String VUE_SUCCES = "/ajoutAbonne.jsp";
  ..........

  public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    String email = request.getParameter("email");
    session.setAttribute("login", email);

    System.out.println("connexion réussie...");
    System.out.println(session.getAttribute("login"));

    this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(VUE_SUCCES).forward(request, response);
}
```

Comment: ajoutAbonne.jsp is at the root level of your webapp? do you see "connexion réussie..." in the console of your AS?

Comment: Yes, i see "connexion réussie" but i stay on the same page. Yes ajoutAbonne.jsp is a the root of my webApp.

Comment: Have you checked the log files of your AS to see if there is any exception?

Comment: The console doesn't display an exception ...

Comment: You need to provide more info allowing people to reproduce following the MCVE rule http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, otherwise your question could be closed

Comment: How do you call doPost?

Answer (score 0):

you can try like bellow

response.sendRedirect("myfolder/welcome.jsp");

or

response.sendRedirect(VUE_SUCCES);